# How to add a link to the theme's footer using a WP plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

Until now I have this.

```
add_action('wp_footer', array($this, 'add_content_footer'));

function add_content_footer()
{
    echo 'my link';
}
```

But this code do not put the link (or whatever) inside the theme's footer. Just add the content at the page's bottom.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to echoing Link anchor
It will print the link (if called on wp_footer - the link will be located on footer)

As an option - you could download any plugin that has this functionality, and search the action, that the link is hooked to